# min sum of consecutive values with Divide and Conquer

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Given an array of random integers

```
N = [1,...,n]
```

I need to find min sum of two consecutive values using divide and conquer.
What is not working here but my IQ?

```
def minSum(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array[0]+array[1]

    if (len(a)%2) != 0:
        mid = int(len(array)/2)
        leftArray = array[:mid]
        rightArray = array[mid+1:]
        return min(minSum(leftArray),minSum(rightArray),crossSum(array,mid))
    else:
        mid = int(len(array)/2)
        leftArray = array[:mid]
        rightArray = array[mid:]
        return min(minSum(leftArray), minSum(rightArray), array[mid]+array[mid+1])


def crossSum(array,mid):
    return min(array[mid-1]+array[mid],array[mid]+array[mid+1])
```

Comment: To start, the very first two lines in the function are bound to raise an index error. Also, kind of confusing that the function for returning the min sum is called `maxSum`

Comment: Why divide-and-conquer? This seems like an exceedingly bad approach for this. Why not just a single loop once over the array?

Comment: I need to approach Divide and Conquer solution. I already resolved this by another methods but need exactly divide and conquer

Comment: Don't use "is" to compare numbers (although it may work here), use == and !=

Comment: fixed name of function and !=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that the first condition is wrong: If `len(array) < 2`, then the following line is bound to raise an `IndexError`. Also, `a` is not defined. I assume that that's the name of the array in the outer scope, thus this does not raise an exception but just silently uses the wrong array. Apart from that, the function seems to more-or-less work (did not test it thoroughly, though.

However, you do not really need to check whether the array has odd or even length, you can just use the same code for both cases, making the `crossSum` function unneccesary. Also, it is kind of confusing that the function for returning the min sum is called `maxSum`. If you really want a divide-and-conquer approach, try this:

```
def minSum(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return 10**100
    elif len(array) == 2:
        return array[0]+array[1]
    else:
        # len >= 3 -> both halves guaranteed non-empty
        mid = len(array) // 2
        leftArray = array[:mid]
        rightArray = array[mid:]
        return min(minSum(leftArray),
                   minSum(rightArray),
                   leftArray[-1] + rightArray[0])

import random
lst = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(20)]
r = minSum(lst)
print(lst)
print(r)
```

Random example output:

```
[1, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 10, 7, 10, 8, 4, 9, 5, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 9]
3
```

However, a simple loop would be much better suited for the problem:

```
def minSum(array):
    return min(array[i-1] + array[i] for i in range(1, len(array)))
```